# Dispatch Redux action after React Apollo query returns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, graphql, react-apollo

I'm using React Apollo to query all records in my datastore so I can create choices within a search filter.

The important database model I'm using is `Report`.

A `Report` has `doorType`, `doorWidth`, `glass` and `manufacturer` fields.

Currently when the query responds, I'm passing `allReports` to multiple dumb components which go through the array and just get the unique items to make a selectable list, like so..

```
const uniqueItems = []

items.map(i => {
  const current = i[itemType]

  if (typeof current === 'object') {
    if (uniqueItems.filter(o => o.id !== current.id)) {
      return uniqueItems.push(current)
    }
  } else if (!uniqueItems.includes(current)) {
    return uniqueItems.push(current)
  }

  return
})
```

Obviously this code isn't pretty and it's a bit overkill.

I'd like to dispatch an action when the query returns within my `SidebarFilter` components. Here is the query...

```
const withData = graphql(REPORT_FILTER_QUERY, {
  options: ({ isPublished }) => ({
    variables: { isPublished }
  })
})

const mapStateToProps = ({
  reportFilter: { isPublished }
  // filterOptions: { doorWidths }
}) => ({
  isAssessment
  // doorWidths
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(
    {
      resetFilter,
      saveFilter,
      setDoorWidths,
      handleDoorWidthSelect
    },
    dispatch
  )

export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps), withData)(
  Filter
)
```

The Redux action `setDoorWidths` basically does the code above in the `SidebarFilter` component but it's kept in the store so I don't need to re-run the query should the user come back to the page.

It's very rare the data will update and the sidebar needs to change.

Hopefully there is a solution using the `props` argument to the `graphql` function. I feel like the data could be taken from `ownProps` and then an action could be dispatched here but the data could error or be loading, and that would break rendering.

Edit:

Query:

```
query ($isPublished: Boolean!){
  allReports(filter:{
    isPublished: $isPublished
  }) {
  id
  oldId
  dbrw
  core
  manufacturer {
    id
    name
  }
  doorWidth
  doorType
  glass
  testBy
  testDate
  testId
  isAssessment
  file {
    url
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

While this answer addresses the specific issue of the question, the more general question -- where to dispatch a Redux action based on the result of a query -- remains unclear.  There does not, as yet, seem to be a best practice here.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that, since Apollo already caches the query results in your store for you (or a separate store, if you didn't integrate them), it would be redundant to dispatch an action that would also just store the data in your store.

If I understood your question correctly, your intent is to filter the incoming data only once and then send the result down as a prop to the component's stateless children. You were on the right track with using the props property in the `graphql` HOC's config. Why not just do something like this:

```
const mapDataToProps = ({ data = {} }) => {
  const items = data
  const uniqueItems = []

  // insert your logic for filtering the data here

  return { uniqueItems } // or whatever you want the prop to be called
}

const withData = graphql(REPORT_FILTER_QUERY, {
  options: ({ isPublished }) => ({
    variables: { isPublished }
  }),
  props: mapDataToProps,
})
```

The above may need to be modified depending on what the structure of `data` actually looks like. `data` [has some handy props on it](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-queries.html#graphql-query-data) that can let you check for whether the query is loading (`data.loading`) or has errors (`data.error`). The above example already guards against sending an undefined prop down to your children, but you could easily incorporate those properties into your logic if you so desired.

Comment: Thanks for this - I've updated my post with the original query but I'll not be able to give your solution a try until I get onto my machine a bit later.

Comment: I updated the example to just use a default value for data. Let me know if you still can't get the expected behavior.